# Pycurl is not compiled against Openssl, when I trie to use wfuzz how to solve this problem?

Tags: openssl, pycurl

I was testing the tool wfuzz on kali linux, and I'm getting this warning.

> Warning: Pycurl is not compiled against Openssl. Wfuzz might not work correctly when fuzzing SSL sites. Check Wfuzz's documentation for more information.

I'm trying to brute force the password in the DVWA  'Vulnerable Web Application'.
I was following this steps: https://ogma-sec.fr/dvwa-brute-force-command-execution-solutions-protections/
unfortunately it didn't work.

So my question is: it is because of the warning?

if Yes how can I compile pycURL against openssl?

by the way: I did flow this steps in the link bellow => https://github.com/xmendez/wfuzz/blob/master/docs/user/installation.rst
and I'm stuck in the  step 10.

Answer (score 18):

Any one still facing the problem or would in future, here are my steps by which I solved the issue.

The thing is in the most of the system pycurl comes pre-installed(pyhton3-pycurl) and that is not compiled with OpenSSL.

So firstly uninstall it. (for Debian based systems)
`sudo apt --purge remove python3-pycurl`

And install the dependencies for `pycurl`:
`sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev`

And then re-install
`sudo pip3 install pycurl wfuzz`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... Sadly there is a high risk that your answer never gets accepted with questions from users that have quite low reputation... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Definitely works! Thanks. I did have to re-link wfuzz in Kali with ln -s /usr/local/bin/wfuzz /usr/bin/wfuzz but it definitely solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still need it, Pycurl use libcurl4-openssl-dev for ssl connections, so try installing it:

`sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

and then upgrade pycurl and wfuzz using pip3:

`sudo pip3 install --upgrade pycurl
sudo pip3 install --upgrade wfuzz`

may you need install pip3 before:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir ~/python-pycurl-openssl
cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl
sudo apt-get source python-pycurl
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pycurl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo dpkg-source -x pycurl_7.43.0.1-0.2.dsc
cd pycurl-7.43.0.1/debian/control
sudo sed -i ‘s/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/libcurl4-openssl-dev/g’ control
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
sudo dpkg -i python-pycurl_7.43.0.1-0.2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Explanation please

Answer (score 0):

I if u use the the "H" switch you should include the following parameter into double quotes regarding the parameter such as
-H "**Host:** test.com", this happened with me a lot!

Hope you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this message.
bash# wfuzz
bash: /usr/bin/wfuzz: No such file or directory

you need to add symbolic link

ln -s /usr/local/bin/wfuzz /usr/bin/wfuzz

Comment: I thinks it's better to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH` or else you will have to add a symlink to each and every package that gets installed there.